# How to source() an external R script using Quarto?

Tags: r, quarto

I'm trying out Quarto and 'converting' my Rmarkdown file into a quarto document. In my old Rmarkdown file, I would use `source("R_datacleaning.R")` and `source("R_Functions.R")` to run the data cleaning and to load some functions. I've also tried `source(here("R_Functions.R"))` but it doesn't work either. The R-scripts and the qmd files are in the same directory.

I can't seem to get that to work in the .qmd. The error I get is `Error: RStudio not running`. I've searched around and looked at the Quarto documentation, but couldn't find anything relating to this. I think there might be something I'm not understanding about the Quarto environment in RStudio. Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Edit:

````
---
title: "quarto_test2"
format: html
---

```{r}
library(here)

source(here("R_Functions.R"))
```
````

Error message is:

```
processing file: quarto_test2.qmd
  |..........                                                            |  14%
  ordinary text without R code

  |....................                                                  |  29%
label: unnamed-chunk-1
Quitting from lines 7-10 (quarto_test2.qmd) 
Error: RStudio not running

Execution halted
```

`R_Functions.R` is in the same directory as `quarto_test2.qmd`, as previously mentioned.

**Version Info**

- RStudio version is `2022.07.2`.
- R version `4.2.0`.
- Quarto version `1.1.245`.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example that is not working for your case and giving errors. Also include information what `quarto` and Rstudio version you are using.

Comment: I didn't feel a need to include a reprex as I'm pretty sure this is not an issue with my code, but with the `source()` function not working in .qmd. Could be a directory issue, or something with knitr, that I'm not understanding. Anyway, I will still update the main post with a reprex if you really want one.

Comment: Yes, please do. Its always a better idea to include a reprex, even it seems trivial (Because what may seem trivial to you, may not seem to others). Anyway, I have used `source()` already several times in qmd files and faced no problem so far :)

Comment: Thanks, I've added the reprex. I see that Quarto was built under R version 4.2.1, but mine is 4.2.0. Not sure if that might be it? Have you used `source()` on .R files? `list.files()` points correctly at my directory and prints `"quarto_test2.qmd"` together with `"R_Functions.R"` Also, the issue/error does not change whether I include `here()` or not.

Comment: Yes. I Have used `source` on R files. By the way, what's the content of your script `R_Functions.R`?

Answer (score 4):

I was successful in pdf with

```
---
title: "source() external R script in Quarto, in PDF"
format: 
  pdf:
    toc: true # table of contents
---
```

Some text...

````
```{r}
#| echo: true
#| eval: false # skip evaluation
#| file: C:/directory/script.R
```
````

Some text...

Answer (score 3):

After much similar frustration I found this:
https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/11361

Essentially add into your setup:

```
project:
     execute-dir: project
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix for me was to use this [`this.path`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=this.path) package:

````
---
title: "quarto_test2"
format: html
---

```{r}
# Load required libraries
library(this.path) # find where you are

# Note current script location
current_script_directory <- this.dir()

# Source some local code
source(file.path(current_script_directory, "R_Functions.R"))
```
````

The above seems to work in R scripts, Rmarkdown, and quarto and should work in RStudio or in the R terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, which gave the exact same errors, however my file path was correct.

I found out Quarto cannot source an external R script if you have this line in the R-script:

```
rstudioapi::writeRStudioPreference("data_viewer_max_columns", 1000L)
```

Posting this answer here (sorry if it is the wrong place, but it was the first that popped up when I initially googled the issue) so future-me can solve it again!